# Running Scala project and sub-project as two separate applications on different ports in Docker using Play Framework

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, sbt

I have a Scala application that is essentially an API service. The API service is a Play application that listens on a specific port when it launches.

I have a separate service that publishes metadata for the API. This metadata service publishes information specific to the API and listens on a different port.

The current structure of my project is where the API application is the root project, and the metadata service is a sub-project.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to build a docker image where both the API and the metadata server are launched within the same container on different ports.

Currently, when the docker container is built, only the API is running but the metadata service is not. However, when I do `sbt run` within the metadata project, it successfully starts up

`build.sbt` for API service:

```
lazy val metadata = (project in file("path/to/api/metadata"))

lazy val api = (project in file("path/to/api"))
  .dependsOn(
    metadata,
  )
  .enablePlugins(PlayService, PlayLayoutPlugin)
  .aggregate(metadata)
  .settings(
    name := "API_NAME_HERE",
    version := "API_VERSION_HERE",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq( // library dependencies defined here
    ),
    packageName in Docker := "DOCKER_URL_HERE/API_PATH_HERE",
    mappings in Docker += (resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "extra.jar" -> "/opt/docker/conf/extra.jar",
  )
```

How can I run two services on different ports in the same docker container, where both are play applications and one is a sub-project of the other?